# Get remote cmd from linux termnal

Tags: telnet, remote-access

I need to run some scripts in a windows remote machine from a terminal linux, I've tried using telnet however in the windows machine it's unable and there isn't installed a ssh server. So I need other way to run the command remotely without a graphical interface.

I have the possibility for run the command from a windows machine, however I need to open a SSH Tunnel to see the remote machine, I've used psexec but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to install software on the remote server?

Your SSH client will not be able to connect to the remote machine unless that machine is running an SSH server to respond to your client's connection request.

There are a number of possible options for SSH servers to run on Windows.
(Google for ssh server windows)

Because SSH gives an external user some access to/control over your server it is designed to be a secure tool. I would therefore recommend using an SSH server which is still actively maintained, and keep it up to date. Servers which are old and no longer supported are are likely to contain known security issues which may never be addressed, thereby leaving your server vulnerable.

There are a number of good free open-source solutions for this, so you shouldn't need to buy anything.

In the past I've worked with Windows machines running Cygwin, with the OpenSSH ssh server installed. Depending how much of the Cygwin system you choose to install, it can make the target Windows host rather like logging into another Linux box in terms of environment.

You can download the installer for Cygwin from http://www.cygwin.com/

Comment: Yes I think in that option, however I don't have access to install new software on the remote server. that's the problem, and the other alternative was use telnet, but it isn't active d.